# CreateJS: how to change color of bitmap image

Tags: createjs

I'm using createJS to build some easy game.

I have an image (white fill and black stroke) and I would change the black color to another.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check this one -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515024/how-i-change-fill-color-of-graphics-in-create-js maybe you shouldnt have an image, you should have a shape and than you should fill the color.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but I have to load an image, not a geometrical form.

Answer (score 0):

The three ways to do color adjustments in EaselJS are:

1. [Composite Operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation): You can draw an image using a composite operation (such as "destination-in") to determine how pixels are laid down. This is probably not going to give you the result you want. [Here is an example](http://lab.gskinner.com/kalogoscope/3) of a black PNG being changed to different colors using compositeOperation.
2. Color Filters. EaselJS has both a [ColorFilter](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/ColorFilter.html) and a [ColorMatrixFilter](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/ColorMatrixFilter.html), which assist with modifying colors. The first uses parameters to multiply and add to the color and alpha channels, but is a little harder to use. The second uses a ColorMatrix to adjust hue, saturation, contrast, and brightness. This may not work for you, since changing the black pixels is kind of the opposite of color filters do.
3. A Custom Filter. EaselJS supports custom filters (such as the [Threshold Filter in the extras folder](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/extras/Filters/ThresholdFilter.js). This is probably your best option, and might take massaging to get what you need.

Hope that sheds some light.

Comment: Ok thanks, third method works perfectly. But now I have another problem. I have two images that I can move. I color this images, and when these are superimposed I must change the color only in this part. like this http://imgur.com/SoPqxoy

Comment: Composite operations can do that to a certain extent. Depending on your required effect, this could be quite difficult. I recommend opening another SO question.